# Simple Loop to Switch Between Methods?

Tags: iphone, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have to methods, `leftSideFade` and `rightSideFade`.

What do I have to write (a loop) so that when `leftSideFade` is finished fading (running), `rightSideFade` will begin, then when 'rightSideFade' finishes, 'leftSideFade' begins again, etc.?

I have BOOLs called leftSideFadeDone and rightSideFadeDone, but I can't think of an appropiate loop.  Do you guys suggest anything?  It would be much appreciated!  :)

Comment: You are sort of describing a "co-routine", but that's not a structure that C-based languages can directly tackle.  You might be able to do it with notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Just have each method call the other as the last line of execution in the method.

I'd note that you need some way to get out of this... so put this call in an `if` that checks some flag on whether or not you need to quit looping.

```
- (void)leftSideFade {
    // do stuff
    [self rightSideFade];
}

- (void)rightSideFade {
    // do stuff
    [self leftSideFade];
}
```

Comment: Yes, you do sorta need that check to see if you should stop.